# How to implement SMS/Email feature in .net/c# application

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, sms, web-hosting

I'm developing an application in which I need to send a SMS and email to user when the user enters his details. I haven't purchased a domain or hosting yet. Below are my queries,

Which hosting should I opt for? I tried contacting godaddy and got to know that I should go with windows vps(virtual private server) to use the SMS feature in an application.

Isn't it possible using Windows hosting, as it's cheaper than purchasing a VPS?

I've heard few API providers. Twilio, TROPO, clickatell etc. Is it possible to use them if I go for windows hosting?

Some other guy is also developing an android application of the same business. So what approach should I use considering the both platform would use the server to implement sms/email feature.

P.S: I've no prior experience in web application public hosting. So any input or advice on the same would be really appreciated.

Comment: you can use a normal shared hosting for having both sms and email , unless you want to run your own gateways or mail server.

Comment: could you help me identify the ways to do it? I'm done with email but couldn't find a better way to implement SMS feature.

Answer (score 0):

[1] Windows shared hosting environment doesn't support SMS because there are lots of SMS provider available in the market and they won't allow and support API integration for all those provider.You can not install SMS software with shared hosting environment too. Though Email service is available with most of hosting provider for their shared hosting environment but SMS facility is not.

[2] Windows VPS is having facility of both because one would have full administrative access of it.So they can utilize mail service offered by hosting provider. One can install software application of SMS and integrate it with SMS provider's API.

Hence you are having VPS hosting is the choice for Email and SMS both service.

Comment: Thanks Bhavishi. So there's no way to implement SMS feature using shared hosting/ I don't want to go for VPS as it costs me an arm and leg.

Comment: Yes, VPS is the solution because on shared environment, one cannot install software one wishes. Please accept reply if you felt query is answered.